# I want to place images into coordinate(x,y) and they are replaceable with new images?

Tags: php, image

I am working with cakephp, and I need to place many amount of small images into coordinates, where each of the image has its x and y values. And at certain points, I'm gonna need an image to be replaced with a new image. Let's say image on the x=10, y=7 needs to be replaced after a certain condition is fulfilled, how can I make it happen? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO, this site is not a place to ask for tutorials or complete solutions but a place to help people with specific problems, you're asking to serve you a solution. You need to show some effort and code. Also this problem can be solved by just spending 1 minute using Google or the SO search function. nor is it related to CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem that cakephp should solve.
My approach would be to construct an array with the image properties, (url,name,order)
then do the rest in javascript.

you can init a grid with images and set a timeout to replace those images properties.
to style it give the image containers some classes that you can animate in css with a transition

for some nice examples:

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/